# c++ visual studio code appears weird on windows command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, powershell, command-line

[opening on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrpau.png)

[opening on powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OboaM.png)

I had the problem of exporting my c++ files from visual studio to my school server/folder, where I would use powershell to open and run the files on the command line. The code is all spaced out and weird font when I open them on file, and it appears as strange characters when I open them on the command line. This causes the code to not run at all.

How do I fix this issue?

edit: I have added some pictures for better reference

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your results. Please edit your question and add a screenshot about the issue. "Spaced out" sounds like it's Unicode encoding issue, double-byte representation adds s p a c e s around each letter.

Comment: @vonPryz I have added some screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because the file is encoded UTF-8 but being read as ANSI or vice-versa (or some other mismatch of encodings). Try navigating to the files directly in powershell, i.e.

```
cd C:\Users\username\source\repos\projectname\projectname
```

if you are using the default path, and open a file with notepad then click 'Save as' and check the encoding (left of save button). The default indicates what encoding is being used, try changing to UTF-8 or ANSI  - whichever the default is not. If that doesn't work you can also try UTF-16 and UTF-32 (which I believe are listed as Unicode and Unicode Big Endian in notepad, but I haven't verified that).

In visual studio, per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2017) article, you can do this from the save dialog by going to `File > Save As` and in the `Save As` dialog you click the down arrow next to `Save` and select `Save with encoding...` The default appears to be code 1252, I would recommend trying UTF-8 first and see if that works.

Comment: I believe that is the issue, I have no idea how to change the coding. My java files work fine from intellij and they are UTF-8, im not sure if its different for c++.

Comment: As I said in the answer you can use notepad to change encoding of a file ex post facto. You can do the same thing in visual studio, I will update my answer to include that

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an encoding problem. The first file starts with Unicode [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) `ÿþ`. That is, UTF-16 little endian. Because UTF-16 uses two bytes for each character and your characters are from ASCII subset, each other byte is `00` - which is rendered as extra spaces.

The second file is harder to dechipher, as Nano doesn't render the characters properly. I'd guess it has exactly the same problem - UTF-16.

It seems that some version of Visual Studio [ninja-changed default file encoding](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169566/visual-studio-2017-creates-utf-16-source-code-file.html) as UTF-16.

As how to fix the situation, save the files in ASCII or UTF8 encoding on your Windows system, then upload those just like @Ghost adviced.